# Tkinter ttk update label style

Tags: tkinter, ttk, tkinter-text, ttkwidgets, tkinter-label

I am trying to update the of the background color of a text label. For this I am using the ttk module of tkinter.

For some reason it doesn't want to execute the `config.xx(style="xx.TLabel`.

```Python
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

win = Tk()
win.geometry("1200x800") #1024*600
s = ttk.Style(win)

s.configure("CustomGrey.TLabel",   background="#4D4D4D", foreground="white")
s.configure("CustomGreen.TLabel",  background="#97D077", foreground="white")
s.configure("CustomYellow.TLabel", background="#FFD966", foreground="white")
s.configure("CustomRed.TLabel",    background="#FF6666", foreground="white")


s.configure("CustomRed.TLabel", background="#FF6666", foreground="white", font=('Time New Roman', 60), anchor= "c")


def updateLabelColor(color):
    if   color == "Green":  battery_lab.config(style="CustomGreen.TLabel")
    elif color == "Yellow": battery_lab.config(style="CustomYellow.TLabel")
    elif color == "Red":    battery_lab.config(style="CustomRed.TLabel")
 
updateLabelColor("Green")
```

The goal is that text can change color in a program. It does not matter if it is done via a tk or a ttk label.

Does anyone know what to do with this?

Comment: If I add the necessary code for a [mre] it works fine. Is it possible that you found yourself in a gotcha where you use the wildcard imported **tkinter.Label** instead of a **ttk.Label** ?

Comment: @Thingamabobs. We talking about ttk not tk

Comment: @Joost.  if   color == "Green":  battery_lab.config(style="CustomGreen.TLabel")
NameError: name 'battery_lab' is not defined

Comment: @toyotaSupra op talking about both in their question, on top of that OP is missing to include the label. So you either guess or wish in your statement but it's far from what is stated here.

Comment: @toyotaSupra you just have to include the label as a ttk.Label and it works. There is no debugging needed, just two lines of code missing. OP needs to clarify what they actually need help with.

Comment: Yes. I know about that too. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you asked for.
If you want to change a `tkinter.Label`'s background color you can easily change it by adding `background` attribute:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
label = Label(root, text="A Text", background="yellow")
label.pack(pady=30, padx=50)
root.mainloop()
```

If you want to change a `tkinter.Label`'s color by pressing a button or getting an input you can do this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def update_Label_color(color):
    if color == "Green":
        label.config(background="green")
    elif color == "Yellow":
        label.config(background="yellow")
    elif color == "Red":
        label.config(background="red")

color_variable = StringVar(value="Green")
input = Entry(root, bg="orange", textvariable=color_variable)
input.pack(pady=10, padx=50)
button = Button(root, width=30, height=5, text="Button", command= lambda: update_Label_color(color_variable.get()))
button.pack(pady=30, padx=50)
label = Label(root, text="A Text", background="white")
label.pack(pady=30, padx=50)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: We're talking about ttk not tk.

Comment: He/She wrote "It does not matter if it is done via a tk or a ttk label."